# Disable input text in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have hml form with two input text

```
<input type="text" wicket:id = "query"/> 
<input type="text" wicket:id= "address"/>
```

I need to implement choose mechanism. When someone start to write query then address should be disable and vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an behavior to the query textfields that listens to onChange event. In the `onEvent` method disable the address textfield and add it to the ajax request target.

See this example how to add the behavior and how to disable the other component. Keep in mind that you might add some checks if the other component has to be enabled or disabled.

```
queryTextField.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onKeyUp") {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            addressTextField.setEnabled(false);
            target.add(addressTextField);        
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Only problem is that onChange (in most browsers?) is fired when the field loses its focus. As I read it, he likes the other field to instantly disable when typing. And don't you think Ajax adds a bit of a overhead? I'd like my GUI responsive :)

Comment: @verhage - thanks for the hint. onChange is the wrong event. I changed it to onKeyUp

Comment: @verhage - yes Ajax is a little bit overhead. But thats the way to go with pure wicket. I would implement a little javascript and handle it all at client side too.

Comment: which will be a breeze with Wicket 6, as WiQuery core becomes an integral part of the Wicket core :)

Comment: You might be interested in also capturing the [`oninput`](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput) event.

Comment: And it will be good if you remove the Ajax behavior after executing onEvent() because it will fire for each keyUp event.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
myTextField.add(AttributeModifier.replace("readonly", "readonly"));
```

Of course, `"readonly"` should be determined based on some criteria on your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a behavior to both fields that disables/enables the other field when onKeyUp event is triggered through JavaScript.